# Q: VBA, find column number (integer) by corresponding header (row 1, string)

Tags: vba, function, for-loop

Hi all I have the following on a sheet (I have a shittonne of data but to keep it simple I use this):

```
Name    Adres    City
Berend  Laan 123 Warsnveld
Jacq    Laan 456 Leiden
Steph   Laan 789 Almere
```

Assuming the column headers stay the same but users add rows, how do I find the column number of the original column headers (Name, Adres, City).

I thought about making a string variable of the headers (strName etc.) and a integer for the column (iColName etc.). 
Then I'd need to check at which column number the pre-set names (strName etc.) match the ones on the worksheet and put this value in the integer variable (iColName etc.), preferably via a loop. This part is where I get stuck.

What do I need to check the string `"Name"`, variable strName (original location 1, 1) to each cell on row 1 (max 255 columns) untill I get a match and put this in the corresponding iColName (this last part is to make copy/paste actions later on and make sure it works, no matter how many columns users have added).

I hope I've made myself clear and I'm looking forward to your responses.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Might be prudent to mention that I'd like to write to or from the workbook with the (possibly altered) data in it.

UPDATE2: In short, I need a loop that checks the string variables of the original headers (these are set beforehand) to all the column headers of the worksheet. When they match, I'd like the column number of the matched header stored in the corresponding Integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `VBA` for this.

If the heading is unique in row one then something as simple as `=MATCH("Adres",$1:$1,0)` will return the column number of *Adres*.  It will return `#N/A` if *Adres* doesn't exist in row 1.

If you really want to use VBA you could use the `FIND` command:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rFoundRange As Range

    Set rFoundRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1) _
        .Find(What:="Adres", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not rFoundRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Found in column " & rFoundRange.Column

        'Copy the cell in row 5 of the found column to A1 of Sheet2.
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, rFoundRange.Column).Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: But the purpose I want to use it for is to find out where to original columns are in the (possibly) altered worksheet and take action based on the new position (which is why it is stored in a variable), and this all in one go, so don't return column x, then y and then z. So I don't quite see how this helps, but that might not mean that your input is wrong, I just don't see how it matches my need.

Comment: Yes, looks like I've completely misunderstood your question.  Rereading your question I'm not clear on what you need - maybe try rewording your question as you haven't had much response.  I'll update or delete my answer as appropriate.